# Cant send php mail but no error is shown

Tags: php, email

Hi,

I am running a Centos 7 but I cant send php mail. I dont get any error whatsoever. The mail simply wont reach its destination.

This is my script:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$to  = $_POST['target'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from_name = mb_encode_mimeheader($name,'UTF-8');
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "To: $name <$to>\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from_name <$email>\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

how can I configure this so it will at least let me know why is not sending the mail?

Thank you.

Comment: try it without manipulating the 'TO' header. i.e comment that line out.

Comment: It didnt work either

Comment: my first step would be to check the mail server logs

Comment: So you have what installed, `sendmail`, `postfix`?

Comment: postfix is installed but not sendmail.

Comment: None of the solutions listed there work for me. I installed sendmail and no use. I also modified my script to show errors but still no error is displayed.

Comment: Help please????

Comment: Hey!! What about some help??? PLEASE HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEELP!!!

Comment: Please help!! What kind of help site is this???